# Scheduler with custom fire time from DB

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I need to write a scheduler (spring 4 application).
I have a number of fire times (start time) in DB. And I can create/delete them manually through UI. For each of this start time I need to invoke the method.

The reason why I can't use native @Scheduled is that:
1) my tasks is not repetitive (but it is not so big deal);
2) I need to handle start time manually. It shouldn't be hard-coded or set in properties. I need possibility to add new trigger in any time from UI without redeploying.

About Quartz Triggers, I'm not sure that it will match my problem. As I see it: I need to write some service that every few second will update all triggers accordingly to times from DB.

So, what is the best approach for my problem?

Comment: Use JPA (or whatever) backed Quartz. Manipulate the tasks through Quartz, not directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to update an existing trigger or replace it by another with quartz. So when you HMI update/add trigger then update/add it in your database and update/add in the scheduler.

Updating an existing trigger:

```
// retrieve the trigger
Trigger oldTrigger = sched.getTrigger(triggerKey("oldTrigger", "group1");

// obtain a builder that would produce the trigger
TriggerBuilder tb = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder();

// update the schedule associated with the builder, and build the new trigger
// (other builder methods could be called, to change the trigger in any desired way)
Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
.withIntervalInSeconds(10)
.withRepeatCount(10)
.build();
//Reschedule
sched.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);
```

Replacing trigger:

```
// Define a new Trigger
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
.withIdentity("newTrigger", "group1")
.startNow()
.build();

// tell the scheduler to remove the old trigger with the given key, and put the new one in its place
sched.rescheduleJob(triggerKey("oldTrigger", "group1"), trigger);
```

[Those examples](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/UpdateTrigger.html) are from the [quartz documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/quick-start.html).

If you choose to use a JDBC JobStore don't write/update anything in directly in the quartz table.

You shouldn't access to the JobStore (for any type of JobStore) you have to use the scheduler interface only.